# Submitting a new APK to the Play Store which has changes that Codepush isn't aware of

Tags: apk, visual-studio-app-center, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am using Codepush to update my React Native Android App so I can make changes without having to submit a new APK.

The problem is, if I change some code and submit this as a new APK without sending it to Codepush, the App downloads a previous version from Codepush once installed. Basically Old Codepush code replaces new APK code.

Is this expected behaviour? Is the only way to avoid this to submit to Codepush at the same time as submitting the new APK?

Is it a case of Codepush matching version numbers, so if I release an APK with a version name of 1.2, Codepush will check its latest "target version" and if it's less not bother updating the app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do.

If my current native version is `1.2.12`, my code-push command looks

```
./node_modules/.bin/appcenter codepush release-react -a <<appname>> -d <<deploymenttype>> -t 1.2* --mandatory
```

As you can see, my target version has wild character to say update for app having binary `1.2.X`.

Next time, I need to generate a native apk. I make sure that I update my minor number in the version. Ex: `1.3.XX`

This way my old code-push bundles are not applied on new build.